# Predicting EMI/EMC Issues from Microcontroller AC Spec Rise time fall time

Tags: microcontroller, electromagnetism, emc, signal-integrity, high-speed

In one of his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52fxuRGifLU) Rick Hartley says signals with fast rise time can cause EMI/EMC issues.

I am using [FS32K148UJT0VLQT](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) in my design. In my board this controller is working at 5 V supply.

Below image shows the AC electrical specifications at 5 V supply. This clearly shows the rise time and fall time of signals. Hope I am looking at correct spec, please correct me if I am wrong.

May I know how I will decide whether the rise and fall time specifications given in the datasheet will cause any EMI-EMC issues or not?

[image]

Comment: So from your data sheet and feynman's answer, you want the default for all your outputs to be configured per the first line in the chart - the one with the 2.8 ns minimum rise time.

Comment: @SteveSh,Feynman said to  make rise and fall times as long as possible.so I need to configure for 17.3 ns .Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I don't think you have to go that far.  For one, to achieve that would mean adding capacitance to your traces.  The 200 pf load condition needed to achieve the 17.3 ns rise time is not configurable via the FS32K...  And if you make the rise and fall time too long, you may violate the transition time requirements of whatever device your driving.

Comment: This needs to be measured. It also matters if you are talking of _conducted_ EMI or _radiated_ EMI.

Comment: I am talking about both  conducted EMI and radiated EMI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to tell just from the datasheet value if rise and fall times will cause EMC problems, as EMC problems are caused by the interaction of many more aspects.

Also keep in mind that rise and fall times in a datasheet are measured at specific conditions that may have little in common with your conditions.

But it's generally good advice is to make rise and fall times as long as possible (to keep the frequency content low) and as short as necessary (to keep the link working). You can increase rise and fall times by placing series resistors at your output pins, for example.

Comment: As one example, I've seen a microprocessor downclocked to 800kHz to reduce EMC. As another, physical specifications like RS-422 have controlled rise and fall times into a defined impedance to limit noise.